# How to send object array which contain mutipart data in ajax call

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

Hello I wanted to send data like below in ajax post method.

[image: Object Array]

Currently I am sending data like this.

```
var data = {
            album_name: $scope.album_name,
            album_description: $scope.album_description,
            category_id: category,
            artist_id: $scope.artist_id,
            album_image: ($scope.image == "" || $scope.image == null) ? "-1" : $scope.image,
            song_files: JSON.$scope.inputs
        };

            method: 'POST',
            url: api_path+"album_add",      
            dataType: 'JSON',   //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined ,'Authorization': auth_token},
            data:  data,
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    if(value || value === '') {
                        if ($.isArray(value)) {
                            for(var i in value) {
                                formData.append(key+'[]' , value[i] )
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            formData.append(key, value);
                        }
                    }
                });
                // var headers = headersGetter();
                return formData;
            }
```

Here song_files in data is my object array which contains value which I have shown in the image there is title,description,image file and audio file.
When I am sending this request it sends the data in [object object] format I am not able to get data like [{title:1,descrption:test,file:file,image: image}, {title:2,descrption:test,file:file,image: image}] this format.

Comment: Read about [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: @GonrasKarols Yes I have tried  in that case I am not able to get files it is sending data like this [{"title":"album 1","$$hashKey":"object:10","description":"album 1","file":{},"image":{}}]

Comment: You need another  loop ... loop over array...then loop over each object. Use `angular.forEach` so it ignores angular properties like `$$hashKey`